# Geometry Nodes How to View Inside Specific Node?

Tags: animation, node-editor, geometry-nodes

So I am following this geometry nodes tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BfOLveHLMaM

and I copied every single step however, at  5:04 when he enters his node it shows this, which basically goes from geometry.nodes.003 -> Mouth Shape and it shows a switch node in his tutorial

[image]

However, when I copy his exact steps and enter the same node it shows this, so the image below is the same exact file path as his, yet mine shows this and only if I tab into it again will show the same screen.

[image]

[image]

Is this a new update since he made his tutorial a few months ago??

Or why does my exact file path not match up with his screen in the tutorial?

Am I using the correct shortcut key to enter a node? When I am on this screen and click on my mouth shape node, do I only press TAB to enter? or do I press something else because he never said in the video what he pressed so I have no idea

[image]

Comment: It's possible to create a node group inside a node group (nodegroupception). So I think you inadvertently pressed CTRL G two times instead of one, creating a nested node group. You can un-group a group with CTRL ALT G while the group is selected

Comment: but would having two groups affect the outcome? or is my 2nd image the same as the tutorial above except im just 2 group deep?

Comment: Yes it is functionally exactly the same thing.